# windows 8 C# read and write simultaneously to a file

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have a process where I am writing byte array to a file (`StorageFile`). The process runs in periodic intervals and during the same time I need to read from the beginning of the file in another process. The two processes are in different classes. When I start reading the file, the write operation fails with access denied error.

Here the file is a `StorageFile` inside the app folder.

The write method calls:

```
IRandomAccessStream randomStream = await targetFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
Stream stream = randomStream.AsStreamForWrite();
```

The read method calls:

```
IRandomAccessStream randomStream = await targetFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
Stream stream = randomStream.AsStreamForRead();
```

Both operations take place **simultaneously from different methods** and it results in an access denied error. Seems **I can use the read/write inside the same method** while opening for write. **But how to do that from different methods??**

Do we have anything similar to the earlier `System.IO.FileShare` so that I can explicitly say that this file needs to be accessed from another location in the same app?

Comment: If this are only methods, use a lock. With this you can mutually exclude

Comment: While writing I'm appending to the end of the stream. I'm not opening the file each time, write a chunk of data and closing the file every time. It may not be possible in my case since both the operations read and write needs to occur continuously...

Comment: use real database, SQLite is supported in win8 modern apps, http://wp.qmatteoq.com/using-sqlite-in-your-windows-8-metro-style-applications/

Comment: I'd ask why?  Why can't the write operation just update whatever the read op wants to read it for?

Answer (score 0):

Besides switching to a database type setup, I would suggest buffering your writes to an array and writing them in chunks based on the buffer filling and/or certain about of time elapsed. Unless you need the latest and greatest performance down to the millisecond, I doubt people will notice a performance impact. You will have to play with the buffer size to make sure you give your reader enough time to actually read the file.

On the reader side, you could implement a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) object on the file.

Comment: Sorry, Seems I could not catch up the entire idea...  Are you suggesting to create an array and write the entire contents to the array so that I can read from the beginning of the array?? If so, I think it won't work since the file size may be larger (sometimes even around 100 MB). If the idea is to use array as a place holder for a chunk of data from where the process can read, then I'm not clear...            The reading from the file is an end user initiative action and so when the end user starts reading the initial 1MB, the file may contain 25MB or more. How can I place them in an array.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher will give us notifications whenever the file has changed. But is it possible for us to get the contents of the file until this point??

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Assuming your buffer is 1024 bytes, you would create a byte array that is 1024 bytes. When the array is filled, you would open the file, write to the file, and close the file. Then clear the buffer and continue the process again. When the file is saved, your FileSystemWatcher would go off, triggering your other process that there is something to read. The key is to minimize the time the file is locked, so each process has a chance to get at the file.

Comment: That's really a nice approach. But unfortunately it won't match with my requirement. Once the app start reading from the file, it is a continuous operation. So I need to do both the operations simultaneously. I need to have read permission to the file continuously...

Comment: Does Win8 have anything equivalent to **System.IO.FileShare?**

Comment: Where is the **continuous** requirement coming from? What is the impact of the buffer? My suggested solution or similar will make it appear continuous while technically not being. Just like "the cloud" is not some entity that cannot be destroyed, it's just a rebranded server room.

Comment: .NET 4.5 includes [System.IO.FileShare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx), so Windows 8 has it...unless you have been talking about WinRT this whole time

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about a WinRT app... Then regarding the continuous requirement, this is like a media file and once the user initiates an action the stream (read stream) will feed data from the beginning of the file to another control. I can't stop it in between, that means the reading once started should be continuous...